# How to use TinyMCE textarea editor as a class?

Tags: php, javascript, css, tinymce, textarea

I have some TinyMCE textarea editor for my PHP programs like this one:

```
<!-- TinyMCE -->

<script type="text/javascript" src="../jscripts/tiny_mce/tiny_mce.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

    tinyMCE.init({
        // General options
        mode : "textareas",
        theme : "advanced",
        skin : "o2k7",
        plugins : >"autolink,lists,pagebreak,style,layer,table,save,advhr,advimage,advlink,emotions,iespell,i>nsertdatetime,preview,media,searchreplace,print,contextmenu,paste,directionality,fullscree>n,noneditable,visualchars,nonbreaking,xhtmlxtras,template,inlinepopups,autosave",

        // Theme options
        theme_advanced_buttons1 : >"save,newdocument,|,bold,italic,underline,strikethrough,|,justifyleft,justifycenter,justif>yright,justifyfull,|,styleselect,formatselect,fontselect,fontsizeselect",
        theme_advanced_buttons2 : >"cut,copy,paste,pastetext,pasteword,|,search,replace,|,bullist,numlist,|,outdent,indent,bl>ockquote,|,undo,redo,|,link,unlink,anchor,image,cleanup,help,code,|,insertdate,inserttime,>preview,|,forecolor,backcolor",
        theme_advanced_buttons3 : >"tablecontrols,|,hr,removeformat,visualaid,|,sub,sup,|,charmap,emotions,iespell,media,advh>r,|,print,|,ltr,rtl,|,fullscreen",
        theme_advanced_buttons4 : >"insertlayer,moveforward,movebackward,absolute,|,styleprops,|,cite,abbr,acronym,del,ins,at>tribs,|,visualchars,nonbreaking,template,pagebreak,restoredraft",
        theme_advanced_toolbar_location : "top",
        theme_advanced_toolbar_align : "left",
        theme_advanced_statusbar_location : "bottom",
        theme_advanced_resizing : true,

        // Example word content CSS (should be your site CSS) this one removes >paragraph margins
        content_css : "css/word.css",

        // Drop lists for link/image/media/template dialogs
        template_external_list_url : "lists/template_list.js",
        external_link_list_url : "lists/link_list.js",
        external_image_list_url : "lists/image_list.js",
        media_external_list_url : "lists/media_list.js",

        // Replace values for the template plugin
        template_replace_values : {
            username : "Some User",
            staffid : "991234"
        }
    });
</script>

<!-- /TinyMCE -->
```

Now I'd like to use **all code above as a class**, something like this:

`<textarea id="test" name="test" class="tinymce"></textarea>`

How and where should I create `class="tinymce"`?

I would like to use this class in many textareas at different php/html programs.

Comment: in your HTML markup !! ie the output that PHP generates

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's an example of applying TinyMCE to specific classes:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
tinyMCE.init({
        mode : "textareas",
        theme : "simple",
        editor_selector : "mceEditor",
        editor_deselector : "mceNoEditor"
});
</script>

<form method="post" action="somepage">
        <textarea id="content1" name="content1" class="mceEditor" cols="85" rows="10">This will be a editor, since it has a selector class.</textarea>
        <textarea id="content2" name="content2" class="mceEditor" cols="85" rows="10">This will be a editor, since it has a selector class.</textarea>
        <textarea id="content3" name="content3" class="mceNoEditor" cols="85" rows="10">This is not a editor since it has a deselector class.</textarea>
</form>
```

Full example: http://www.tinymce.com/tryit/selector_deselector.php

Answer (score -1):

here you can find complete reference for TinyMce.

http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/js/tinymce/docs/api/index.html#class_tinymce.html

Good luck.